# Rails 3 - complex query with joins and counts, possible subqueries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, subquery

Ok, so i have a bit of a complex query i am trying to come up with in my rails application. I have four tables: Clients, Projects, Invoices, Invoice_Line_Items.  I am trying to get certain bits of data from all of those tables and display it in a "reports" type view in my application.  This is what the structures look like for the four tables:

**Clients**

```
 |  id  |  name           |  archive  |
----------------------------------------
 |   1  |  Client 1       |     0     |
 |   2  |  Client 2       |     0     |
```

**Projects**

```
 |  id  |  client_id  |  name           |  archive  |
------------------------------------------------------
 |   1  |      1      |  Project 1      |     0     |
 |   2  |      1      |  Project 2      |     1     |
 |   3  |      2      |  Project 3      |     0     |
 |   4  |      2      |  Project 4      |     1     |
```

**Invoices**

```
 |  id   |  client_id  |  project_id  |  name           |  archive  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   1   |      1      |      1       |  Invoice 1      |     0     |
 |   2   |      1      |      1       |  Invoice 2      |     0     |
 |   3   |      1      |      2       |  Invoice 3      |     1     |
 |   4   |      1      |      2       |  Invoice 4      |     1     |
 |   5   |      2      |      3       |  Invoice 5      |     0     |
 |   6   |      2      |      3       |  Invoice 6      |     0     |
 |   7   |      2      |      4       |  Invoice 7      |     1     |
 |   8   |      2      |      4       |  Invoice 8      |     1     |
```

**Invoice_Line_Items**

```
 |  id   |  invoice_id  |  name         |  amount_due  |
---------------------------------------------------------
 |   1   |       1      |  Item 1       |     500      |
 |   2   |       1      |  Item 2       |     500      |
 |   3   |       2      |  Item 3       |     500      |
 |   4   |       2      |  Item 4       |     500      |
 |   5   |       3      |  Item 5       |     500      |
 |   6   |       3      |  Item 6       |     500      |
 |   7   |       4      |  Item 7       |     500      |
 |   8   |       4      |  Item 8       |     500      |
 |   9   |       5      |  Item 9       |     500      |
 |   10  |       5      |  Item 10      |     500      |
 |   11  |       6      |  Item 11      |     500      |
 |   12  |       6      |  Item 12      |     500      |
 |   13  |       7      |  Item 13      |     500      |
 |   14  |       7      |  Item 14      |     500      |
 |   15  |       8      |  Item 15      |     500      |
 |   16  |       8      |  Item 16      |     500      |
```

Ok, hope those diagrams make sense enough.  What i am looking for as a result set is this (example data set taken from above example data):

```
 |  clients.name   |  current_projects  |  archived_projects  |  total_amount_due  |  total_amount_paid  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Client 1       |  1                 |  1                  |  2000              |  2000               |
 |  Client 2       |  1                 |  1                  |  2000              |  2000               |
```

Ok, so here's what's going on there:

1. Getting all *non-archived* clients
2. Getting a count of all *non-archived* projects
3. Getting a count of all *archived* projects
4. Getting a total_amount_due from the invoice_line_items table that is a sum of all of the *non-archived* invoices
5. Getting a total_amount_paid from the invoice_line_items table that is a sum of all of the *archived* invoices

I am relatively new to Rails and this is a fairly complex query (at least in my head). Please let me know if there is a simpler solution that i am overlooking or if i am just over complicating it.  If i need to do multiple queries in my controller that's fine, i was just wanting to see if i could get away with one sql call.  I'm pretty sure i can do this pretty easily with some subqueries but i'm not sure how to write those in the controller in Rails.

Thanks for any help or direction you can provide and if this question is just outrageous or whatever just let me know and i'll delete it and go search the Googles more (have tried already to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well i ended up figuring out a solution myself.  Not quite sure it's the best solution....feels heavy and messing but i just created quite a few objects in the controller to get the sql statements i needed to pull the data from the database.  I basically have one object for each column (**column**, *not* each row).  Let me know if anyone can figure out a better solution.